# How to mask last parentheses brackets in string using java replaceAll(regex, replacement) method?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to

```
ASDFASDFG => A********
(qwe)rtya(sdfg)h => (qwe)rtya(s***)h
```

so i tried to

```java
public String setMask_ (String name_){

    String result = null;

    if(name_.lastIndexOf("(") > -1) {
        // Bracket Begin 
        int locBrkBgn = name_.lastIndexOf("(") +2;
        // Bracket End 
        int locBrkEnd = locBrkBgn + (name_.substring(locBrkBgn, name_.length())).indexOf(")") -1;
        // result = name_.replaceAll("(?<=.{"+locBrkBgn+"}).*(?={"+locBrkEnd+"})", "*");
        result = name_.replaceAll("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", "*");
    } else {
        result = name_.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).", "*");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

oh, I think I did it.

```
public String setMask_ (String name_){

    String result = null;

    if(name_.lastIndexOf("(") > -1) {
        // locate. Bracket Begin 
        int locBrkBgn = name_.lastIndexOf("(") +2;
        result = name_.replaceAll("(?<=.{"+locBrkBgn+"}).(?=[^\\)]*?\\))", "*");
    } else {
        result = name_.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).", "*");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

result = name_.replaceAll("\(\w+\)\w*$", "(*" + name_.replaceAll("\(\w*\)\w*\(\w*\)", ")"));

Basically, you replace the part inside the second parenthesis with * and then replace everything until last closing parenthesis with the closed parenthesisparenthesis.